# deleting data from datagridview using sqldataadapter

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a datagridview with a data in sql server, I want to delete the selected rows using dataadapter this is my code

```
DialogResult dr;

dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this User?", "Delete User", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tb_Accounts WHERE AccountID=@AccountID", conn);
    da.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@AccountID",SqlDbType.Int).Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows;


    conn.Open();
    da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

My error is cannot find table 0, I don't know what's that..

Comment: Wherr is ds variable defined?

Comment: why don't you use SqlDataAdapter.Update() to delete your row?